# if NSString does not equal function?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have searched all over the place for this, including apple's docs on NSString (maybe I didn't see?) but I am trying to find a method in xCode for checking wether a NSString does not equal to something. Much like

```
if (myNSSting = @"text" {...
```

except specifically I want to check if it does not equal to 'text'.

Comment: `not (x equal y)` is [almost always] the same as `x notEquals y`. In any case, `=` is never valid (and `==` is very rarely valid) for comparing strings in Objective-C.

Comment: Retagged: Nothing to do with Xcode

Comment: Yep, `=` is assignment, not comparison.  `==` compares addresses, so will only be true if you're comparing a string object to the exact same string object (not just one that looks like it).  `isEqualToString` compares strings by character content.  (Note that essentially the same is true for regular C, C++, Java, and several other languages.)

Comment: And all animals are equal, but some are more equal than others.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
 if(![myNSString isEqualToString:@"text"])
```

Answer (score 3):

For case insensitive compare we can handle by:

```
 if( [@"Some String" caseInsensitiveCompare:@"some string"] == NSOrderedSame ) {
      // strings are equal except for possibly case
    }
```