# objective-c : if statement not working properly

Tags: objective-c

This isn't the whole code but I'm trying to get this to look to a textview box and see if a value has been put in. If not I want it to do the first bit if not I want it to go to the else... however whatever I do it just crashes or doesn't work.

```
-(IBAction) sendPressed{

    if((youtubeurl.text = @"")){
        //if it doesnt have value
        NSLog(@"no youtube clip");
        youtubelink = @"";
    }
    else{
        //if youtube url has been entered
        NSLog(@"youtube clip found");
        completeurl = youtubeurl.text;
        youtubelink = [completeurl substringFromIndex:16];
    }
```

Comment: what type is youtubelink ? if that's not NSString it is bad idea to assign strings to it , (that would be youtubelink.text = @"")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if NSString does not equal function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375815/if-nsstring-does-not-equal-function)

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement is performing an assignment.  You probably intend for it to be performing a comparison.  Also, you should not use `==` for comparison of `NSString`s.  Try something like this:

```
- (IBAction)sendPressed {
    if([youtubeurl.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        //if it doesnt have value
        NSLog(@"no youtube clip");
        youtubelink = @"";
    }
    else{
        //if youtube url has been entered
        NSLog(@"youtube clip found");
        completeurl = youtubeurl.text;
        youtubelink = [completeurl substringFromIndex:16];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([youtubeurl.text isEqualToString:@""])
```

This is the correct if statement. A single = is an assignment, not an equality check. Besides, you can't compare strings with ==. This way you compare pointers.

Another option is to check the string length:

```
if (youtubeurl.text.length > 0)
```